# What is the format that Microsoft access stores date/time information?

Tags: ms-access

MS access stores date - time info as a number. I opened the .mdb file and the date time info is a big number. Is this encoded data?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a format, it's the *day count* since 1899-12-30 00:00:00 as a decimal.